# Load Div Content After Document Its Ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

How to load div content when html finished loading ( $(document).ready )

Example i have div class="test" and on class test i have a ads banner or photo how i can make it so test will be loaded after the website is done loading ? Mainly idea would be to increase website load speed by doing this

Comment: You have an answer in your first line of the question

Comment: "Mainly idea would be to increase website load speed by doing this" --- why do you think it makes the page slower?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a lazy loading solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as below;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  loadAds();
});

function loadAds() {
  //Logic to load ads
 //May be something like $(".test").html("Your content here");
}
```

Comment: How much i know im not allow to put the ads script on javascript (js file) becouse this i need to be like example

<div class="test"><script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script></div>

But i need some way first to "test" to be block loading and after the page its ready loading the content of "test"